# Do I need to GRANT ALL to the OWNER of a table in a PostgreSQL 9.3 Database?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, privileges, user-permissions

Looking at some tables in pgAdmin, I can see table definitions with the following statements

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  OWNER TO user_name;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE table_name TO user_name;
```

Other tables in the same database omit the second `GRANT ALL` statement, and I suspect it is redundant, given that `user_name` is already the `OWNER` of `table_name`.

So, is the `GRANT ALL` redundant in this case, and if so am I able to remove its definition (from the `table_name` > Properties > Privileges tab)?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably not but see below.

Owners by default have full rights on the table, and note they can also grant rights on their own tables.  This is independent of any rights given to public.  See:

```
chris=> create table footest(id int);
CREATE TABLE
chris=> revoke all on footest from public;
REVOKE
chris=> insert into footest values (1);
INSERT 0 1
chris=> revoke all on footest from chris;
REVOKE
chris=> insert into footest values (1);
ERROR:  permission denied for relation footest
chris=> grant all on footest to chris;
GRANT
chris=>
```

So unless you already revoked the permissions you do not need to grant them.